# using MapperScannerConfigurer with spring3, mybatis, and mybatis-spring

Tags: spring, mybatis

in my **applicationContext.xml** i have the following

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="formularyDb" />
    <property name="configLocation"  value="file:/web/sites/drugformulary-spring/config/mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="file:/web/sites/drugformulary-spring/mappers/*.xml" />
    <!--<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:org/myd/formulary/mappers/*.xml" />-->
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <!--<property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.dao" />-->
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster" />
</bean>
```

if i have the
**property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster"**
, my DAO(DrugMasterDao) in org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.dao is not found I get the *error:

Invalid bound statement (not found):

But if i change it to **property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.dao**,  DrugMasterDao is found

I would like to have my dao's in the same packages with its controllers and services. So i am wondering how do i do this (use MapperScannerConfigurer) with different dao's in different packages? They will be all under org.myd.formulary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked

```
<bean id="drugmasterScanner"  class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.**.dao"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out how [jpetstore](http://mybatis.github.io/spring/sample.html) code structure looks like. Mapper interface is meant to map sql statements defined in your xml config, then you could simply inject or autowire automagicaly created mapper beans into DAO beans. lets say(assume that mapper interface is MyMapper):

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.persistence" />
</bean>

<bean id="myDAO" class="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.dao.MyDAO">
    <property name="mapper" ref="myMapper" />
</bean>
```

Comment: thank you for responding. I looked at the petstore originally, but it has all the persistence interfaces in one package. I am trying to keep our original structure (earlier version of spring and using ibatis) where our persistence interfaces(Dao's) are in the same package as the controller and service. I have the auto mapper beans being created OK only if i put them all in the same package –

Comment: I haven't used it, but have you considered using <mybatis:scan />? According to documentation it searches packages recursively and you could define marker interface.

Comment: i tried <mybatis:scan base-package="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster" /> but did not work had to add  <mybatis:scan base-package="org.myd.formulary.drugmaster.dao" />, so it looks like it does not search recursively other packages. I will go and research mybatis:scan and see if there are some params that can be set

Comment: Only possible issues I could think of are deffined in mybatis-spring.xsd "Note that only interfaces with at least one method will be registered; concrete classes will be ignored." though first statement might be outdated since 1.1.0 [version](https://github.com/mybatis/spring/blob/f2c126de393be4e012a3d06a9c70b56d3016ea2e/src/test/java/org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperScannerConfigurerTest.java)